# Combine text and a fontawesome icon in facet titles in a ggplot2 chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, font-awesome

Is it possible to insert an icon from fontawesome in a facet title of a ggplot2 chart?

I would like to combine an icon with text:

Using a new column, that pastes the fontawesome-icon to the label does not. Is there another way to achieve this?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(emojifont)

mpg %>% 
mutate(fa_class = paste0(fontawesome('fa-linux'), class)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = year, y = displ)) +
geom_point() +
facet_wrap(~ fa_class)
```

The icons are not recognized:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find an easy fix using `fontawesome()` but since you are using `emojifont` you could use the `emoji()` function and then change the font family.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(emojifont)

mpg %>% 
  mutate(fa_class = paste(emoji("car"), class)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = displ)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ fa_class) +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(family = "EmojiOne"))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! Why is it harder with `fontawesome()`? In the end, I wanted to use `fa-icons`